# Can I remove knee braces in garage?

Tags: framing

My 1955 california home has exposed knee braces, connecting the wall to the ceiling (photo shows garage).   Can these be removed, or replaced perhaps with a sistered joist?

Removing them would really open up possibilites for wall mounted cabinet storage.  The living room (with flat roof) is above the garage.  I can't find any mention of these braces in home building books, or the internet.

[image: garage knee braces]

Comment: Are there other houses in the same neighborhood with these braces? Or other houses by the same builder with these? Is this a detached garage? Was it built after the house by an amateur?

Comment: What do they attach too on the other side of the wall?  Was the plywood wall added at a later date?

Comment: Yes other neighborhood houses also have the braces, but note the hood is a hodge-podge of different years and builders.  The main home sits above garage, so its attached at the ceiling.  I assume they are original to the house, there are no orig builder plans availale.
The 1x6 braces straddle a 2x4 stud, the same way you see on the joist.  The plywood 'artwork' is my contribution from a year ago to be able to hang anything anywhere.

Comment: Also, perhaps noteworthy, the walls do have diagonal bracing from sole to top plate

Comment: I would suggest that you buy or build "wall mounted cabinet storage" that fits ***between these braces*** - removing them is a phenomenally bad idea. *But hey, it's not like you ever have earthquakes that will collapse your unbraced house...*

Comment: California + Diagonal Bracing = Earthquake Preparation. But... ignore 1906 if you want. (Or 1989)

Comment: I don't disagree about earthquakes, but this is the first home/apartment that I've lived in, out of 10+ in california, that has had these braces.   And I can't find any literature that says if you live in CA, you need to build your house a certain way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those were almost certainly added for a reason since even in 1955 builders did not add extra components to a structure needlessly.

You will need a building permit and in order to get that you'll need plans.  For those plans you'll need an engineer's stamp since you are changing the structure in a major way.

My recommendation is to hire a licensed engineer who can examine your current structure and give you some options to accomplish what you want.